# How to pass dynamic options (function()) to Highcharts from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am currently using the Highcharts library in an AngularJS controller.
Our Highcharts options are server-side computed in JS and sent in a JSON to the client.
It works very well for simple options.
Example 1:

```
/** SERVER SIDE **/
JSON.stringify(
{
        title: {
            text: "My title"
        }
});
```

But I can not pass dynamic options like a function.

Example 2:

```
/** SERVER SIDE **/
JSON.stringify(
{
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
        }
    }
});
```

On the client side, we parse and use the Highcharts.chart() function to generate the chart.
https://jsfiddle.net/christophes/s4vweyh0/4

Would you have a javascript trick to be able to pass functions in a JSON and interpret them on the client side then.
Otherwise, do you know if I can add these dynamic options (functions) client side after loading the chart (with jQuery for example)?

> remark : I would like to define the dynamic options in an angularJS scope and execute Highcharts.chart(...); in his child scope. How can I access to this variable from the parent scope ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply split definition of formatting options and leave it in some static JS file, and only pass relevant data from server

Checkout the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7envzj8/)

Or code below

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
 tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
        }
    }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
      text: "My title"
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, 
I think the setOptions function is applied globally to all Highcharts in the page. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options
Do you know another way to add options only on one chart?

Comment: 1st option is that you can just merge 2 objects into one option. Like `Highcharts.chart('container', {...serverData, ...tooltipOptions})`

Comment: 2nd one is to save return value of Highcharts and then update its option: `var chart = Highcharts.chart(...); chart.update(tooltipOptions);`

Comment: The second seems to solve my problem but I would like to send define the dynamic options in an angularJS scope and execute Highcharts.chart(...); in his child scope. How can I access to this variable from the parent scope ?

Comment: Beign fair, I think my angularjs knowledge are not enough to provide you good answer. So it might require additional searches on SO

Comment: I have found a solution by using $broadcast... thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>


var myFunc = "Highcharts.chart('container', { title: { text: 'My title'  }, tooltip: { formatter: function () {       return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +                 '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';  }    },     xAxis: {         categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']     }, series: [{         data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]     }, {         data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]     }] });"; 


$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = new Object();
    data.func = myFunc;
    var jsonVal = JSON.stringify(data);
    var newObj = $.parseJSON(jsonVal);
    eval(newObj.func);
});
```

Try this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93gsx7eh/).

Actually you can encapsulate the chart function inside a javascript variable. You put this variable containing the function inside an object. After that you transform the object in JSON string and send it to the client.
 On the client side you will receive the JSON variable, evaluate it and run the function.

Comment: Thanks Wolfetto,
actually, it's a good idea but I can't do it easily because my function Highcharts.chart() is located in a common service AngularJS... This service is based on the library ng-highcharts. The directive get the options via a JS Object...

Comment: I have added a remark in the description, I would like to send define the dynamic options in an angularJS scope and execute Highcharts.chart(...); in his child scope. How can I access to this variable from the parent scope ?

Comment: @christophes , I don't think my angularjs knowledge is strong enough to provide best answer :) This is probably deserves another question/searching on SO